# PHP Merge and group arrays and sum them up

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the  following arrays which return the values based on certain calculations :

```php
print_r($adult_array);
print_r($children_array);
print_r($senior_array);

//Adult array start
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [travel_plan] => Business
        [premium_price] => 1336.81
        [eligibility] => Up to 75 Yrs
        [lower_limit] => 0
        [upper_limit] => 75
        [no_travellers] => 2
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [travel_plan] => Holiday
        [premium_price] => 22960.81
        [eligibility] => Up to 75 Yrs
        [lower_limit] => 0
        [upper_limit] => 75
        [no_travellers] => 2
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [travel_plan] => Schengen
        [premium_price] => 11740.81
        [eligibility] => Up to 75 Yrs
        [lower_limit] => 0
        [upper_limit] => 75
        [no_travellers] => 2
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [travel_plan] => Student
        [premium_price] => 22960.81
        [eligibility] => Up to 30 Yrs
        [lower_limit] => 0
        [upper_limit] => 30
        [no_travellers] => 2
    )
)
//Adult array end 

//Children array start 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [travel_plan] => Student
        [premium_price] => 5740.205
        [eligibility] => Up to 30 Yrs
        [lower_limit] => 0
        [upper_limit] => 30
        [no_travellers] => 1
    )
)
//Children array end 

//Senior array start
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [travel_plan] => Senior
        [premium_price] => 38714.41
        [eligibility] => 76 to 85 Yrs
        [lower_limit] => 76
        [upper_limit] => 85
        [no_travellers] => 1
    )
)
//Senior array end
```

The above array output is retrieved and held by different variables. I would like to merge/group the arrays depending on the travel plan and at the same time sum up the premium rates for all similar travel plans. So that there is only one array per travel plan and a sum of the premium price per travel plan.

How can I achieve this? The output should be the following :

```
    Array(
        [0]=>Array(
            [travel_plan] => Business
            [premium_price] => 1336.81
            [eligibility] => Up to 75 Yrs
            [lower_limit] => 0
            [upper_limit] => 75
            [no_travellers] => 2
        )
        [1]=>Array(
            [travel_plan] => Holiday
            [premium_price] => 22960.81
            [eligibility] => Up to 75 Yrs
            [lower_limit] => 0
            [upper_limit] => 75
            [no_travellers] => 2
        )
        [2]=>Array(
            [travel_plan] => Schengen
            [premium_price] => 11740.81
            [eligibility] => Up to 75 Yrs
            [lower_limit] => 0
            [upper_limit] => 75
            [no_travellers] => 2
        )
        [3]=>Array(
            [travel_plan] => Student
            [premium_price] => 28701.015
            [eligibility] => Up to 30 Yrs
            [lower_limit] => 0
            [upper_limit] => 30
            [no_travellers] => 2
        )
        [4]=>Array(
            [travel_plan] => Senior
            [premium_price] => 38714.41
            [eligibility] => Up to 30 Yrs
            [lower_limit] => 0
            [upper_limit] => 30
            [no_travellers] => 1
        )
    )
```

I have tried the  following function but it adds up all the  values to one :

```
        $final_package = array();

        foreach ($travel_plan as $key => $values) {

            foreach ($values as $label => $count) {


                // Create a node in the array to store the value
                if (!array_key_exists($label, $final_package)) {
                    $final_package[$label] = 0;
                }
                // Add the value to the corresponding node
                if(is_string($count)){
                  $final_package[$label] = $count;  
                }else{
                   $final_package[$label] += $count; 
                }

            }
        }

// Sort the array in descending order of values
        arsort($final_package);

        print_r($final_package);
```

Giving me the  following output as the  final array :

```
Array
(
    [premium_price] => 103453.855
    [travel_plan] => Senior
    [upper_limit] => 85
    [eligibility] => 76 to 85 Yrs
    [lower_limit] => 76
    [no_travellers] => 1
)
```

Comment: Would be easier if you can provide example data of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please add your code effort what you have tried so far.

Comment: [4]=>Array(
            [travel_plan] => Senior
            [premium_price] => 5740.205
            [eligibility] => Up to 30 Yrs
            [lower_limit] => 0
            [upper_limit] => 30
            [no_travellers] => 1
        )  explain the calculation of premium_price to get "5740.205" in array

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge(array1,array2,....)` will be your answer.
Here is an example.

```
$a = [
  [
      'travel_plan '=>'Schengen',
      'premium_price '=>'Rs 1,200'
    ],
  [
      'travel_plan '=>'Business ',
      'premium_price '=>'Rs 1,300'
    ]
];

$b = [
  [
      'travel_plan '=>'Senior ',
      'premium_price '=>'Rs 1,600'
    ]
];

$c =array_merge ($a,$b);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($c);
```

The Output will be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [travel_plan ] => Schengen
            [premium_price ] => Rs 1,200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [travel_plan ] => Business 
            [premium_price ] => Rs 1,300
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [travel_plan ] => Senior 
            [premium_price ] => Rs 1,600
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

This logic will solve 90% percent of your problem all you need to do is to extract upper limit and lower limits.

```
$bigArray = array_merge($adult_array, $senior_array, $children_array);


$BusinessTravels =  sortByTravelPlan('Business', $bigArray);
$StudentTravels =  sortByTravelPlan('Student', $bigArray);
$SeniorTravels =  sortByTravelPlan('Senior', $bigArray);
$SchengenTravels =  sortByTravelPlan('Schengen', $bigArray);

print_r($BusinessTravels);
print_r($StudentTravels);
print_r($SeniorTravels);

$finalResult = array_merge($BusinessTravels, $StudentTravels, $SeniorTravels, $SchengenTravels );


function sortByTravelPlan($type, $bigArray){
    $Array = [];
    foreach ($bigArray as $key => $value) {
        if($value['travel_plan'] == $type){
            array_push($Array, $bigArray[$key]);
        }
    }
    return processArray($Array);
}

function processArray($array){
    $result = [];

    $prev_price = null;
    $max_age = null;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $result['travel_plan'] = $value['travel_plan'];
        if($value['premium_price'] > $prev_price){
             $result['premium_price'] = $value['premium_price'];
        }
    }

    $result['upper_limit']  = 30;
    $result['lower_limit']  = 0;
    $result['no_travellers'] = count($array);
    return $result;
}
```

Output resulting from your array is below 
https://3v4l.org/4X2ts#output

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this way.

```
$full_array = array_merge($adult_array,$children_array,$senior_array);
$result = [];
foreach($full_array as $item){
    // Count how many index
    if(isset($result[$item['travel_plan']])){
        $result[$item['travel_plan']] += 1;
    }else{
        $result[$item['travel_plan']] = 1;
    }

    // Sum total value
    if(isset($result[$item['travel_plan'].'_total'])){
        $result[$item['travel_plan'].'_total'] =         $result[$item['travel_plan'].'_total'] + $item['premium_price'];
    }else{
        $result[$item['travel_plan'].'_total'] = $item['premium_price'];
    }
}
```